How to Convert HTML to PDF, or Redirect to Browser in Flutter
i need help with a Flutter project. I need to export a highly styled PDF. I have an HTML file the imports a JSON and converts a HTML page for printing, i need export this html page in PDF.
Is there any libary for HTML to PDF conversion? Or libary to redirect the HTML page to a browser,I use android and PC to export project.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_widget_from_html_core/flutter_widget_from_html_core.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {  
  String stringHtml = """
  <html>
    <body>
      <h1>Hello, World!</h1></br>
      <h2>sub Hello World</h2>
      <button onclick="window.print()">Esse Botão Vai imprimir</button>
    </body>
  </html>
  """;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            HtmlWidget(
              stringHtml
            )
          ]
        )
      )
      ,
      // floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      //   onPressed: _incrementCounter,
      //   tooltip: 'Increment',
      //   child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      // ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}


try this package
flutter_html_to_pdf

Use this package
flutter_html_to_pdf: ^0.7.0
flutter_widget_from_html_core: ^0.15.2

Try this code if that's code is help you
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_html_to_pdf/flutter_html_to_pdf.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';


class PdfPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const PdfPage({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<PdfPage> createState() => _PdfPageState();
}

class _PdfPageState extends State<PdfPage> {
  String stringHtml = """
  <html>
    <body>
      <h1>Hello, World!</h1></br>
      <h2>Sub Hello World</h2>
      <button onclick="window.print()">Esse Botão Vai imprimir</button>
    </body>
  </html>
  """;

  Future<void> _generatePDF() async {
    try {
      final Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
      final String tempPath = tempDir.path;

      final pdfFile = await FlutterHtmlToPdf.convertFromHtmlContent(
        stringHtml,
        tempPath,
        "example_pdf",
      );

      if (pdfFile != null) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(content: Text('PDF Saved: ${pdfFile.path}')),
        );
        print('PDF generated at: ${pdfFile.path}');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error generating PDF: $e');
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(content: Text('Error generating PDF')),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.picture_as_pdf),
            onPressed: _generatePDF,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _generatePDF,
              child: const Text('Convert HTML to PDF'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


i try, but i don't understand how to create the object FlutterHtmlToPdf, this object is imported from libarey or it need instaneced?, anyway i run an get this error on execute
"No implementation found for method convertHtmlToPdf on channel flutter_html_to_pdf"
